# Obtener total de dos input y diferencia de dos fechas automaticamente

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, dom

Tengo este código la diferencia de la fecha funciona pero tengo que presionar un botón para que llama la función lo que deseo es que sin presionar botón me aparezca la diferencia igual para el total de dos input

```js
function calcular() {
  var fechaini = new Date(document.getElementById('fechaini').value);
  var fechafin = new Date(document.getElementById('fechafin').value);
  var diasdif = fechafin.getTime() - fechaini.getTime();
  var contdias = Math.round(diasdif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var preciodia = document.getElementById('preciodia').value;
  var preciototales = Math.round(contdias * preciodia);


  if ((new Date(fechaini).getTime() > new Date(fechafin).getTime())) {
    alert('la fecha es menor');
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('dias').value = contdias;
    return true;
  }
  if (preciototales == null) {
    alert("error al obtener el total");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('preciototal').value = preciototales;
  }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado / investigado como se sugiere en [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Si tu pagina se muestra con los valores cargados al inicio simplemente introduce la llamada la función que has declarado para que se ejecute.

```
function calcular() {
  var fechaini = new Date(document.getElementById('fechaini').value);
  var fechafin = new Date(document.getElementById('fechafin').value);
  var diasdif = fechafin.getTime() - fechaini.getTime();
  var contdias = Math.round(diasdif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var preciodia = document.getElementById('preciodia').value;
  var preciototales = Math.round(contdias * preciodia);


  if ((new Date(fechaini).getTime() > new Date(fechafin).getTime())) {
    alert('la fecha es menor');
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('dias').value = contdias;
    return true;
  }
  if (preciototales == null) {
    alert("error al obtener el total");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('preciototal').value = preciototales;
  }

}

calcular();
```

Si por el contrario los valores son introducidos por el usuario y quieres que se muestre el resultado sin pulsar un botón debes asociar la función a eventos tales como onKeyUp o onBlur de los input donde escriba. En este caso debes controlar excepciones al intentar convertir a fechas.